# React Native using Atom IDE

Tags: atom-editor, react-native

How Can I use Atom IDE for React Native App. I am new to programming and trying my hands on app development in Android.

Can someone post a tutorial or a link for this.

-- Thanks

Comment: you need tutorial for atom?

Comment: install IDE from https://atom.io/ and few packages of atom for react native to make coding easier by feature such as autocomplete, different color text for different keywords

Comment: for autocomplete please go through https://atom.io/packages/atom-react-native-autocomplete

Comment: @codesinngh. Need a small demo of how to use atom for react-native. I am a electrical engineer and have no  clue on coding. Heard Atom is a free and good IDE

Comment: have you downloaded the atom?

Comment: Yes I have. @Codesingh

Comment: On left panel there is an option of add project folder

Comment: Yes there is. @Codesingh

Answer (score 12):

1) Download Atom from https://atom.io/

2) you can add some packages for react native in atom to make it easier to differentiate between different keywords,  statement etc.

3) Download package from here [https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=react+native](https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=react%20native)

4) after downloading above described things then open Atom and on left there is developer panel where you can find add project folder.

5) Upon clicking add project folder, you can browse to the directory where your project is kept, add the project by selecting and then clicking open.

6) On developer's panel, your project directory will display, open any file in your project by clicking the file

Happy coding :)

Comment: thank you for your reply @codesingh . Also will atom be connected to android sdk emulator for live changes what ever code I try to type in it?

Comment: No, If you change javascript file inside atom it would be captured by watchman of react native. when you run server watchman automatically start loading latest changes.